# Unable to build the image in docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

When trying to build the image, i'm getting the error below. I am also adding the related project files.

- Dockerfile
- docker-compose.yml
- **init**.py
- manage.py

Error:

```
Building users-service
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.6.1
ERROR: Service 'users-service' failed to build: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp 52.206.156.207:443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.1

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ADD ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /usr/src/app

CMD python manage.py runserver -h 0.0.0.0
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:

  users-service:
    container_name: users-service
    build: .
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - 5001:5000 # expose ports - HOST:CONTAINER
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

# instantiate the app
app = Flask(__name__)

# set config
app.config.from_object('project.config.DevelopmentConfig')


@app.route('/ping', methods=['GET'])
def ping_pong():
    return jsonify({'status': 'success',
                    'message': "pong"})
```

manage.py

```
from flask_script import Manager

from project import app

# configure your app
manager = Manager(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Comment: There's a network problem or a server of the Docker hub is down.

Comment: OMG, and that is after S3 was down ...